# FOP image not found when using fop 2.3 version

Tags: java, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have upgraded FOP version from fop 1.1 to fop 2.3 version but getting

> org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent Image not found.

Below are the code snippets modified for upgrading.
Master View code using fop 2.3

Code:

```
  TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
  Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();

  FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();

  //foUserAgent.setURIResolver( this.getURIResolver() );
  transformer.setURIResolver(this.getURIResolver());

  Fop fop = null;
  Source src = new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(foDoc));

  if (this.getContentType().equals("application/pdf"))
  {
    fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, foUserAgent, os);
  }
  else if (this.getContentType().equals("application/postscript"))
  {
    fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_POSTSCRIPT, foUserAgent, os);
  }
```

View code for fop 2.3

```
protected static final FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(new File(".").toURI(), resolver);
```

XSLT code

```
<fo:external-graphic src = "stylesheets/Anthem_Join_In.bmp"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

The API for the Resolver have changed and it is poorly documented. This code works for me (fop 2.3) in a JSF webApp.

```
final ServletContext sc = (ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext();

// Create ServletContext resource Resolver
ResourceResolver resolver = new ResourceResolver() {
    @Override
    public Resource getResource(URI uri) throws IOException {
        return new Resource(sc.getResourceAsStream(uri.toASCIIString()));
    }

    @Override
    public OutputStream getOutputStream(URI uri) throws IOException {
        URL url = sc.getResource(uri.toASCIIString());
        return url.openConnection().getOutputStream();
    }
};

// Buid the factory
FopFactoryBuilder builder = new FopFactoryBuilder(new URI(sc.getContextPath()), resolver);
FopFactory FOP_FACTORY = builder.build();
```

The rest of the previous code in my project remains unchanged. I am not using transformer.setURIResolver(...)

The xml fop code looks like this:

```
<fo:external-graphic width="auto" content-width="164pt" height="auto" src="url(/resources/img/main-logo.png)"/>
```